# Angular ngModel doesn't update when `ngModelChange` keeps value

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a text field represented as: `field = {text: "", valid: false}`, and an input with `[(ngModel)]="field.text"`.

I want to make that field only accept a defined set of characters (for this issue, numbers), and doing `(keypress)` doesn't work on mobile, so I did: `(ngModelChange)="fieldChanged(field)"`

The method does the following:

```
fieldChanged(field) {
    console.log(field.text);
    field.text = Array.from(field.text).filter((char:string) => "0123456789".indexOf(char) != -1).join("");
    console.log(field.text);
}
```

And it's behaviour is extremely weird.

Legend:
- input: what key was pressed
- before update: first `console.log`
- after update: second `console.log`
- output: what I see on screen in the input

```
| input   | before update | after update | output |
|---------|---------------|--------------|--------|
| ""      | ""            | ""           | ""     | <- starting position, no event
| "a"     | "a"           | ""           | "a"    |
| "a"     | "aa"          | ""           | "aa"   |
| "4"     | "aa4"         | "4"          | "4"    |
| "a"     | "4a"          | "4"          | "4a"   |
| "a"     | "4aa"         | "4"          | "4aa"  |
| "4"     | "4aa4"        | "44"         | "44"   |
```

Why does it always update the output when I enter a legal character? It should be working for each event call.

**Edit:**
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qrv2ZT1mCI4i482kozDq?p=preview)

Comment: can you create a plunker

Comment: @Aravind added in edit

Comment: if the below answer helped you

Comment: @Aravind It did solve the issue, but in a workaround kind of way. I will use it if no other solution is available

Comment: nothing works in the plunker

Comment: I _think_ you've got the wrong tag on this -- your Plunker, eg, uses Angular 2, and the solution from @GünterZöchbauer works verbatim in Angular 2+. I'll remove the `angularjs` tag, but let me know if that was on purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the cause is that modifying the value on `ngModelChange` breaks change detection, for example if you change the value back to the previous value, because an invalid character was added.

A workaround:

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

fieldChanged(field) {
    console.log(field.text);
    field.text = Array.from(field.text).filter((char:string) => "0123456789".indexOf(char) != -1).join("");
    console.log(field.text);
    var tmp = field.text;
    field.text = null; // or some other value that normally won't ever be in `field.text`
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    field.text = tmp;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // I guess this 2nd call won't be necessary
}
```

Comment: I guess you are right for the reason, because this does solve it. I'll wait a bit to see if anyone has a solution that is not a bodge.

Comment: Sure, no worries. It's 100% up to you if you accept an answer and which one.

Comment: `// I guess this 2nd call won't be necessary` After testing, you are correct, sir. ;) In case it's helpful: Normal change detection will occur after the assignment, and since Angular is now comparing to `null` (a value registered w/ Angular during the first `detectChanges`) instead of the previous value (which could *also* have had `tmp`'s value), it'll _always_ detect `field.text = tmp;` as a change [if it's not null]. I wonder why it wouldn't before, though. Won't the ref to the string have changed? Does that mean Angular is doing a value-based comparison for change detection on strings?

Comment: Angular compares to a value that is the same as the new value and decides nothing has changed. An additional forced change detection with a value guaranteed to be different makes Angular detect a change at the next cycle (after the sync code execution is completed). The root cause is that Angular does not detect when fields are modified, but only that old and new values are different when change detection is run after the end of an event handler.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone having the issues in updating the value, use setTimeout function while updating

```
// setTimeout function
setTimeout(() => {
  field.text = temp;
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}, 1);
```