# ngModel update is not reflected when I manipulate the updated value in ngModelChange

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

Here are my TS and HTML files of a component:

```html
<input type="text" [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="setValue($event)">
```

```js
value: string;

setValue(value: string) {
   const pattern = /[^0-9]/g;
   this.value = value.replace(pattern, '');
   console.log(this.value);  // <- When value is 123a, it puts 123 correctly
}
```

**Stackblitz is added here:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-model-number

---

It's to replace any non-numeric letters in the value. But the input element is not updated.

So if I input `abcd`, the input element should be empty but it's not changed.

But as soon as I input a number, for example, `abcd1`, then the input element shows `1` correctly.

However, the console.log above shows that the `this.value` is updated correctly.

Any idea why it's happening?

---

I've tried to use `input` instead of `ngModelChange` but it's the same.

```html
<input type="text" [ngModel]="value" (input)="setValue($event.target.value)">
```

Comment: Why not just use `<input type="number">`?

Comment: Because I dont want a user to input like `000123`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[New]**

I found the proper way to do it ([repo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-model-number-bpacds?file=src/app/app.component.ts)).

First, the html needs to two-way data-bind the ngModel property.
Then listen to the `input` event and change there the value of the ngModel.

Before inserting the new value to the input, first detect the changes in it and **after that**, set the new value.

```html
<input type="text" #input [(ngModel)]="value" (input)="setValue(input.value)" />
```

```js
constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

public setValue(value: string) {
  const parsedValue = value || "";
  this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  this.value = parsedValue.replace(this.pattern, "");
}
```

---

**[Old response, with ReachtiveForms]**

I'd say that [updating the value in those events breaks the change detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43213682/6951173).

I have reproduce your case using the [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) method and it works nicely.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-model-number-ppqajh?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it not possible with just `ngModel`? And I tried to use changeDetectorRef to trigger changes manually but it didnt work as well. Why it breaks the change detection?

Comment: I honestly don't know, I tried to do the same with ngModel but it didn't work.

Comment: Found a way to do it with ngModel, I updated my response.

Comment: Nice. What happens if it skips the manual change detection?

Comment: If you don't set the `this.changeDetector.detectChanges()` it just doesn't modify the value at all.